# Геолокация API Яндекс через webview не в том месте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, android-webview

Слепили простое приложение через webview c пользовательским слоем в API Яндекс Карт. К сожалению при отладке на реальном устройстве геолокацию ставит за сотни километров от меня. Все время в одном месте (под Волгоградом 48.622 43.165), хотя сидим в Новороссийске. При этом в браузере (по IP) определяет нормально-в городе. Протокол исходной страницы защищенный https. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

https://kontiki-exploration.com/tiler/map_L-37-XXXIV-2.1.html

Comment: "Реальное устройство" как получает координаты? Через мобильного оператора?

Comment: Реальное устройство по идее использует gps. Я правильно понимаю? Не мобильную сеть...

Comment: Судя по геолокации, очень похоже на IP, а где ваш сотовый оператор приземляет связь, это в каждой зоне происходит по своему. У меня мобильник, если ему задать цель определять локацию по IP, вместо Новосибирска показывает то Красноярск, то Омск.

Comment: Виктор, Вы правы. Определение происходит по IP. В мобильнике watch.Position вообще не работает. Определение происходит только при нажатии кнопки из панели управления. На компьютере определение происходит через watch.Position. Есть ли у Вас идеи, почему не работает в мобильнике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию API Карт использует два метода для геолокации: API устройства/браузера и IP адрес. Если вы не указали приоритетный метод геолокации, то API автоматом выберет результат, который вернул более точный результат.

Попробуйте проверить [на этом примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation?from=SO), где определяется местоположение каждым из методов. Возможно в вашем случае стоит прямо в коде указать конкретный провайдер геолокации, но, как вам правильно написали в комментариях, реузльтат будет отличаться для разных устройств и сотовых операторов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я попробую с этим кодами - отпишусь. Но заранее кажется, что дело в чем-то другом. Ведь геолокацию показывает в сотнях километров от реального места..

Comment: При геолокации по IP часто невозможно определить местоположение точнее, чем до страны. В любом случае, тут дело не в API Карт.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. В Вашем примере определяется только красный балун. Геолокация идет только по IP через устройство. Не могу понять, почему у меня не работает определение по gps. Все разрешения на gps прописаны в манифесте и мэйнактивити.джава.

Comment: Я использую вот этот код: navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;    
  var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([latitude,longitude], {
                    }, {
                        preset: "islands#geolocationIcon"
                    });

                map.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

Comment: Можно ли при использовании watch.Position или getCurrentPosition прописать явно провайдера? Или это тоже не поможет?

Comment: лучше задайте отдельный вопрос, как внутрь webView пробросить геопозицию устройства, почему-то на уровне карты она недоступна.

Comment: Текст этого вопроса будет примерно такой же как здесь. Вы считаете так лучше сделать?

Comment: да, это уже второй вопрос и он не про API Карт) Уверена, вам с ним гораздо лучше помогут люди, занимающиеся мобильной разработкой.

Comment: спасибо. Я правильно понял, что указание провайдера тут не поможет, так как координаты вообще через провайдера браузера не определяются?

Comment: похоже на то, иначе в примере из песочницы отобразились бы обе точки - там два раза определяется геопозиция, по разу с каждым провайдером.

Comment: Да и прошу Вас, объясните, что значит "Геолокация на уровне карты недоступна"

Comment: могу ошибаться, но кажется, что из webView недоступно API геолокации устройства. Карта внутри webView и не может получить эти данные. Но повторюсь, это предположение.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за участие.